# change color of first letters of few words of a string using css

Tags: css

I have a string "I am a good person." I need to highlight the first letters of words 'I', 'good', 'person' - I, G, P using css. Is this possible?

```
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <td width="70%" class="heading"><strong>I am a Good Person</strong>
      </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Thank you..!

Comment: You need to split the string to multiple ones like `<div>I</div>`, `<div>Good</div>`, ... and style it with the Pseudo-Selector [::first-letter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)

Comment: Without changing your html (and css only), no, it's not possible

Comment: you need javascript to do this

Comment: @PatrickMlr The ::first-letter only works on block or inline-block elements, not on `<span>`

Comment: @kalsowerus Oh, Thank you!

Comment: @PeterLeupold [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated in HTML5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.highlight{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <td width="70%" class="heading"><strong><span class='highlight'>I</span> am a <span class='highlight'>G</span>ood <span class='highlight'>P</span>erson</strong>
      </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Use span tag and add your style to highlight.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one solution for this.

For more information, see the [::first-letter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) Selector.

```css
td div::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <td width="70%" class="heading"><strong><div>I</div> am a <div>Good</div> <div>Person</div></strong>
      </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use span tags like this:

```
<td width="70%" class="heading"><strong><span>I</span> am a <span>G</span>ood <span>P</span>erson</strong>
```

And then use a css rule like:

```
.heading strong span{
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/pharesdiego/pen/Vreqzy I think something is working here